# Navbar links surrounding centered brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have an idea and not sure how to get it to work.

I have a bootstrap navbar on my site that has links and a "brand". The brand is centered within the navbar using this modification. [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/mQh8DyRfWY)

Instead of setting the navbar up like this:

{ (link)(link)(link)(....bunch of empty space....)(BRAND)(....bunch of empty space....)(link)(link)(link) }

I would like the navbar to set up like the diagram bellow.

{ (....bunch of empty space....) (link)(link)(link)(BRAND)(link)(link)(link) (....bunch of empty space....) }

I am very new to coding so please give me some time on the response to any questions you may have.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding to the left of the first link.

Comment: that did it but when i change screen sizes the padding ends up pushing the links through the brand

Comment: I cannot see the updates, but if I understand correctly, you can make a div surrounding the links, make a width size.

Comment: Also with that div, you can do float:right. But again I cannot see the updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Center 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BRAND</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Center 3</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li.navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9483/